# How can i compare two arrays that have different sizes?

Tags: c, arrays

I have to compare the elements of an array from a file to that of a given array in order to replace them with values from a third array that correspond with the second array.

I tried looping through both arrays and comparing them but since they are not the same size it does not work.

```
int decrypt(char *letters,char *array1,char *array2,int count)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<28;j++)
        {
            if(*(letters+i)== *(array1+j))
            {
                *(letters+i)= *(array2+j);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The decrypted message is: %s\n",letters);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output ? Otherwise it is difficult to make out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You must `break;` from the inner loop after a match was found, otherwise the letter might be replaced again. Suppose the decoding arrays are

```
char array1[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .";
char array2[] = " .QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
```

When the letter `'C'` is decoded it will become `'Q'`, but if you don't break out of the inner loop, the `'Q'` will again be decoded to `'G'`. I suggest

```
int decrypt(char *letters, char *array1, char *array2, int count)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 28; j++)
        {
            if(letters[i] == array1[j])
            {
                letters[i] = array2[j];
                break;                      // added here
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The decrypted message is: %s\n", letters);
}
```

Note that if the input message contains lower-case letters, they should be detected, converted to upper-case, decoded, and converted back to lower-case.